# Angular 8 - IE11 has a "Uncaught in Promise error"

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, httpclient, angular-promise

I updated an app to Angular 8 and I get this Uncaught (in promise) error, 
on loading the app and the network dashboard shows nothing (It's a virtual box win8).

I've read, that you could/must in former versions insert "text" instead of json into the request header - but is this state of art? What should I do? Disable differential loading? I've not read something about httpClient polyfills or something.

I have this in a data service:

```js
 getJobs(workshopGuid: string, active: any = 1) {

 this.httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
};

let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('YII_CSRF_TOKEN', this.csrfToken)
  .append('data', JSON.stringify({workshopGuid, active}));

return this.httpClient
  .get(this.getJobsUrl,
    {
      params
    },
  ).toPromise();
  }
```

and this in the calling method

```js
  setJobList(workshopGuid, isActive) {
    this.jobDataService.getJobs(workshopGuid, isActive)
      .then((data: any[]) => {
          this.dataStore.jobs = data;
          this.dashboardJobList.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).jobs);
          this.visibilityService.setBusy(false);
        }
      );
  }
```

[image]

Solved by adding a catch - but get no error - a cache issue?? Thanks

Comment: Complete your question first if you want help! in which line does the error occur? what is the response from your server? we won't guess

Comment: This error occurs on loading the app and the network dashboard is empty. I'm using a virtual box win8

Comment: Add a catch to the promise and see if there's any helpful information there. What's the status code?

Comment: Ok I add a catch and now it is working without error, maybe a cache problem? Thanks for watching!